# References to Zoroastrianism in Hindu scripture?

Tags: other-religions

Are there any references to [Zoroastrianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoroastrianism#History) in Hindu scripture? The reason I ask is because Zoroastrianism might have come from Hinduism.

Comment: They are related to Hinduism. I had posted similarities of both. Not necessary that everything would originate from Hinduism